# Renaming many files in Mac OS X, batch processing

Tags: macos, command-line, regex, rename, batch

I used to rename file in Linux via a rename command:

```
rename 's/old_pattern/new_pattern/g' *glob
```

Is there something similar in Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)?

Comment: The following article explains how to install `rename` on Mac OS X: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050630022203488

Comment: The backticks are not showing up in your comment - you should probably add this as an answer or edit your question to include your solution.

Comment: The best quick solution I've ever found has been using the built-in Automator. Check out this article for easy step by step help: http://www.tuaw.com/2008/11/11/mac-automation-rename-multiple-files-efficiently/

Comment: I would vote up nilay's answer if it wasn't a comment...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Clumsy me:

```
for i in *.yourfiles; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/old/new/g'`"; done
```

And if you want to use it like I do often this way:

```
rename 's/old/new/' *.files
```

I recommend to use this litte script in ~/bin/rename:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
SUBSEXPR=$1
shift
for i in $@; do mv $i `echo "$i" | sed $SUBSEXPR`; done
```

Comment: your script doesn't work for me "rename ACDC AC-DC ACDC*" result-> "ssed: can't read ACDC: No such file or directory" , I installed rename util from linux and now it works anwyay

Answer (score 52):

With [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), a package manager for OS X:

```
brew install rename
```

Then you can run the same `rename` commands as in Linux.

Comment: You can use MacPorts package as well: port install p5-file-rename

Comment: @MiquelAdrover: But with port you need to use `rename-5.22` (where 22 is the installed version) instead of `rename`

Comment: You can rename the symbolic link
`sudo mv /opt/local/bin/rename-XXX /opt/local/bin/rename`

Answer (score 29):

Use the power of ZSH wisely (type `zsh` in the terminal if you are one of those poor souls who don't use it by default):

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*).htm' '$1.html'
```

ZMV follows [MMV syntax](http://www.unixref.com/manPages/mmv.html).

Comment: but does that also allow regex replacement? This seems to be just some kind of enhanced shell globbing.

Comment: @brubelsabs: Yes, **zmv can do regexp replacement**.

For files that match `*user*.html`, change the extension to `.html` and change all occurrences of `rc` to `final`:

`zmv '(*user*).htm' '${1//rc/final}.html'`

@ghoppe: I think the *zmv* example in your answer needs `-w` or parentheses around its wildcard.

Comment: I really like this suggestion because you don't need to install anything extra on a Mac (like brew), but it does allow you to use the easy mmv like syntax.

Comment: +1 Nice. Couple of differences from regexs I'm used to: 1) use `*` instead of `.*` to get all. `*?` seems to work like non-greedy `.*?`. 2) for me, `^` and `$` for start and end of string seemed to cause it to match nothing

Answer (score 5):

You can try to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and install the `renameutils` package:

> renameutils @0.10.0 (sysutils)
>
> renameutils is a set of programs
>   designed to make renaming files faster
>   and less cumbersome

Comment: this package don't have the "rename" command.

Comment: i didn't say that it does. `qmv` looks like it does the job.

Comment: `qmv` is a great tool, while a bit too much work for simple regex renames, it's fantastic for intelligently naming and moving big numbers of arbitrary files

Answer (score 4):

There are various version of *rename*. It looks like you are looking for the Perl-based one.

One version of this utility comes with the [File::Rename](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Rename/) Perl module. You can install it with something like `sudo cpan -i File::Rename`.

Or, you could go with the [*rename* from Debian's *perl* package](http://git.debian.org/?p=perl/perl.git;a=blob_plain;f=debian/rename;hb=HEAD). It is just a single file to download. Put it where ever you like and *chmod* it so that it is executable.

---

An alternative is the [*zmv* tool that comes with *zsh*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zshcontrib.1.html). It does not have the same syntax, but it does come with your OS and it can easily take care of many of the common cases.

Comment: the [perl rename](http://git.debian.org/?p=perl/perl.git;a=blob_plain;f=debian/rename;hb=HEAD) is what this question shows as an example.

Answer (score 2):

On Macs I use Aristotle Pagaltzis's freely available `rename`, which like Debian's is Perl-based. You can get it [here](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/). Or visit [here](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/rename) to read it first - always a good idea.

You need to place that somewhere in your `$PATH` and make it executable (`chmod +x rename`) and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be difficult but apparently it is. Example,
I want to rename all file's extension from aiff to aifc.

```
find . -iname "*.aiff" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.aiff}.aifc"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a GUI, try [Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/).  It has a "preview" feature that shows what will happen if you follow through with the renaming.

Answer (score 1):

the equivalent command in [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) (cross-platform) is

```
$ renamer --regex --find 'old_pattern' --replace 'new_pattern' *glob
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like Sublime Text's multiselect you could use it with qmv:

> qmv --editor="/usr/bin/s3 -w" files

Answer (score 0):

I just went ahead and found my favorite I've seen referred to as perl-rename giving the `rename` command where help looks like this:

`Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]`

That's how I know I got the one I like.

For Mac, even in Homebrew they have others where  I just vaguely remember having trouble.  So it's not the `rename` package, and it's not the nongnu `renameutils` package either.

Got it from here and just did the install like they mention: https://github.com/subogero/rename