# rename command in osx

Tags: macos, command-line, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming many files in Mac OS X, batch processing](https://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing)

Hi,
  how I can rename a many files with command line in osx?
in linux exits a "[rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)" command, exist a similar in osx?

Comment: Very nearly duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing/

Comment: brew install rename

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install the `renameutils` package:

> renameutils @0.10.0 (sysutils)
>
> renameutils is a set of programs designed to make renaming files faster and less cumbersome

Comment: I prefer [brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)  ;
brew install rename

Comment: I notice that renameutils does not contain a 'rename' port (http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/).  I'd be interested to see which command you substitute for rename and the usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it without the command line, there is Automator. You can me a workflow with the rename Finder items action, and this allows you to (among other things) to substitute parts of a name with something else. You could apply this to to selected items or make it a folder action etc..