# Batch TRIM (RENAME) a specific keyword from set of files

Tags: shell, python, applescript

I have few files namely - "a.mov-, attachment", "b.mov-, attachment", "c.mov-, attachment",etc..
I want to trim the keyword: **"-, attachment"** from all files in that folder.

Please suggest me an approach which script will be best suited for this - AppleScript, Shell, Python etc. (I being a non-scripting guy).

***Note: I m using MacOSX-Maverics[Terminal].***

Comment: You should find a answer here for OSX: http://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just the shell:

```
for f in *", attachment"; do
    mv "$f" "${f%, attachment}"
done
```

The form `${f%something}` returns the value of the variable `f` with the text following the `%` removed from the end of the value.

```
$ var="hello world"
$ echo "${var%orld}"
hello w
```

If you put a glob pattern in there, the shortest match will be removed with `${var%pattern}` and the longest match with `${var%%pattern}`

```
$ echo "${var%l*}"
hello wor
$ echo "${var%%l*}"
he
```

If the pattern does not match the end of the string, nothing is removed

```
$ echo "${var%foo}"
hello world
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Thanks but it failed: bash-3.2$ for f in *", attachment"; do
>     mv "$f" "${f%, attachment}"
> done
mv: rename *, attachment to *: No such file or directory

Comment: This worked : for f in *", attachment.mov"; do mv "$f" "${f%, attachment.mov}"; done

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rename` command if you're using linux:

`rename 's/-, attachment//' *attachment`

with a GUI, there is a lot of tools like ANT Renamer for example.

Comment: Any Idea how to make it work on MacOS?

Comment: have you read the other question on this subject?
`brew install rename` ?